# Duplicate rows in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Inserting to database is k. But then, database is returning same value twice! I tried many things. Don't know, where I am going wrong. This is how it returns with one entry!!!
[image: ![enter image description here]

Please help. My code(view, controller, and model) is:

**View**

```
function customerBarCode(){
                var itemCode=document.getElementById('customerbarcode').value;
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    data:({itemCode:itemCode}),
                    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>inventory/itemMaster/customerBarCode_c",
                    success:function (data){
                      var data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                      if (data.status==true){
                        alert();
                        var tabledata=data.tableData;
                        var q=$("#example-1");
                        $("#example-1").find('tbody').empty();
                        $("#example-1").find('tbody').html(data.tableData);
                      }
                    }
                  })
}
```

**Controller**

```
function customerBarCode_c(){
            $result=$this->itemMaster_m->customerBarCode_m();
            $tabRow ="";
            $i=1;
            $status='i';
            foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                $tabRow.= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td id="eacctCol" class="eacctCol">'.$row['customer_name'].'</td><td class="bar code"><data-id="barCode'.$i.'">'.$row['BARCODE'].'</td><td class="description"><data-id="desc'.$i.'">'.$row['DESCRIPTION'].'</td><td><button type="button" style="background-color:transparent; border-color:transparent; color:red" id="btnDel"><i class="fa fa-close" data-id="close'.$i.'"></i></button></td><td>'.$row['CUSTOMER_CODE'].'</td><td>'.$status.'</td></tr>';
                $i++;
            }
            if($result){
                $response=array("status"=>true,"tableData"=>$tabRow);
            }
            else{
                $response=array("status"=>false);
            }
            echo json_encode($response);
}
```

**Model**

```
function customerBarCode_m(){
        $itemId=$this->input->post('itemCode');
        $query=$this->db->query("select A.*,B.ACCTNAME as customer_name from customer_bar_code A, ledger_accounts B where A.CUSTOMER_CODE=B.ACCTCODE and ITEM_CODE='".$itemId."'");
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: No, it is outside for loop

Comment: :> sorry . It's a little bit hard to read your code  :)

Comment: Am really sorry about that. I am completely new to web development.

Comment: Look like your current select query have no problem . may be it can be a problem when you insert data ... :<

Comment: but data insertion is working correctly -:(

Comment: help plz!!!!! Dont know how to change model being displayed as a code.

Comment: how is that done!!

Comment: Plz help me with the answer too dears...

Answer (score 0):

Replace your model query with following:

```
$this->db->select("A.*,B.ACCTNAME as customer_name");
$this->db->from('customer_bar_code A');
$this->db->join('ledger_accounts B','A.CUSTOMER_CODE=B.ACCTCODE and ITEM_CODE="'.$itemId.'"');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Also, note that your all the table cell containing the customer_name have same id which can be prefix or postfix by some unique value or identifier to maintaining uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks for ur helping hand. But, unfortunately, it returned an empty form

Comment: truncate the ITEM_CODE condition from the join and use $this->db->where('ITEM_CODE',$itemId); instead.

Comment: Still, an empty form :-(

Comment: it would be more helpful, if you can share your database schema.

Comment: As i told before, I am new to PHP. So,......... sorry that I dint get u :-(

Comment: can you share the database structure for both the table "customer_bar_code" & "ledger_accounts" which you have built?

Answer (score 0):

One way of fixing the "duplicate row problem" is to use the SQL `GROUP BY` clause.

So change your model function to something like this:

```
function customerBarCode_m(){
        $itemId=$this->input->post('itemCode');
        $query=$this->db->query("select A.*, B.ACCTNAME as customer_name from customer_bar_code A, ledger_accounts B where A.CUSTOMER_CODE=B.ACCTCODE and ITEM_CODE='" . $itemId . "'" . ' GROUP BY ITEM_CODE');
        return $query->result_array();
}
```

This way, you are guaranteed to get rows which have different `ITEM_CODE` values.

Comment: try grouping with more "unique" fields, such as the barcode

Comment: `GROUP BY ITEM_CODE, BARCODE`

Comment: let me try...plz stay with me

Answer (score 0):

tbody was somewhere else also, in the view. Hence both tbody displayed.So, changed this below line,

$("#example-1").find('tbody').html(data.tableData);

to this below,

$("#example-1").find('tbody').eq(0).html(data.tableData);